# jquery validation submit not firing

Tags: jquery

I have read all through the docs and web and don't understand how to submit the form once it is valid. I'm using post (does that matter?) in my form. The alert in my submitHandler is not firing.

```
//Contact Form Section
$("#formContact").validate({
errorLabelContainer: $("#formContact div.formerror"),
rules: {
    Name: "required",
    Email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
    },
    Message: "required" //minlength: 2
},
messages: {
    Name: "Please enter your name (at least 3 letters)",
    Email: {
        required: "We need your email address to contact you",
        email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
    },
    Message: "Please tell us how we may help you..."
}
submitHandler: function(form) {
    alert("Form submitted!"); //form.submit();
}       
});
```

Comment: whether the validation rules are working?

Comment: you are missing comma after message and submitHandler

Comment: missing `,` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dLh4w8vu/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of the error in syntax. Add the comma and the try the code.

```
$("#formContact").validate({
errorLabelContainer: $("#formContact div.formerror"),
rules: {
    Name: "required",
    Email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
    },
    Message: "required" //minlength: 2
},
messages: {
    Name: "Please enter your name (at least 3 letters)",
    Email: {
        required: "We need your email address to contact you",
        email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
    },
    Message: "Please tell us how we may help you..."
},
submitHandler: function(form) {
    alert("Form submitted!"); //form.submit();
}       
});
```

Comment: Yep, it was missing a comma (shame). Now that the submit is "handled", where do I write my code to do stuff with the form contents? Let's say I write a function formProcesssor, do I call it in the submit? form.submit(formProcessor())

Comment: You want to process the form elements in jquery itself or in PHP?

Comment: hmmm... seems like PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed a comma

```
//Contact Form Section
$("#formContact").validate({
errorLabelContainer: $("#formContact div.formerror"),
rules: {
    Name: "required",
    Email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
    },
    Message: "required" //minlength: 2
},
messages: {
    Name: "Please enter your name (at least 3 letters)",
    Email: {
        required: "We need your email address to contact you",
        email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
    },
    Message: "Please tell us how we may help you..."
},
submitHandler: function(form) {
    alert("Form submitted!"); //form.submit();
}       
});
```

might work